# Icon background

Tags: android, background, icons

Minor issue - the icon for my app is something I pulled off the web and it has a white background which looks a bit rubbish on screen (circled below):

[image]

I'm using the icon like this in my manifest:

```
android:icon="@drawable/mpg"
```

I guess I could paint the background black but I'd lose the pipe. Also, on my real phone, my background is a wallpaper, so replacing the white with black isn't going to help

Any idea how to make the white round the object translucent?

Comment: Yes: redo the icon (remove the white background). You can only make it in a graphical editor

Comment: How do I 'remove' a white background?

Comment: You need to use something like paint to clean up the background. This is not a programming related question

Comment: remove whitebackground with transperant layer....

Comment: Make the image a layer. Select all the white bg. Delete it

Comment: OK, apologies - I thought there would be a programmable attribute I could set...thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

use photoshop to edit this photo , and make extension of photo .PNG 
this extension accepte icon without background